# WordPress get_posts function

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to fetch WordPress posts id, title, and other details using get_posts() as shown in the below guide:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/

I wish to exclude post_content from the result fetched using the function. Is there any argument that I can pass to the get_posts() to exclude the post_content?

Comment: By default you can't exclude any parameter. What you can do is iterate through response and prepare another array, object and push only required items or you can unset the unused parameter in loop.

Comment: I wonder why you would want to exlude the post_content from the results, could you elaborate?

Comment: I have multiple WordPress sites and managing them all in a single place. I'll wish to display all WordPress sites with the post details (excluding post_content), due to post_content size it takes time to fetch via CURL call.

Comment: If you're concerned about loading times by using a cURL, you might want to look into the RESTful API of WordPress and retrieve data through AJAX calls. AJAX calls can be done asynchronous and will speed up loading times.  https://www.excellarate.com/blogs/a-modern-way-of-ajax-in-wordpress-using-rest-api/

You can build a custom API that will deliver the exact information you're looking for per site, then bundle them and return them to whatever location you need the info.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No.

### Method 1

However, you can use the `$fields` filter to return just the `ids` of the retrieved posts.

`$args = ['fields' => 'ids']`

And insert the filter into your get_posts() by using:

`get_posts($args);`

If you have retrieved the ids, you can use those in a custom loop to retrieve any meta-data you wish, related to the post by using a nifty little function WordPress provides us called `get_post_meta`. Which you can use, depending on your coding style, like this:

```
foreach($posts as $post)
{
    $theThingYouNeed = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thethingyouneed', true);
    // do something with $theThingYouNeed
}
```

### Method 2

As provided by zipal_

After retrieving the posts, you can loop through them and unset the post content like so:

```
foreach($posts as $post){
  unset($post['post_content']
}
```